# Can Python 2.7.16 be built with openssl 1.1.1?

Tags: python, openssl

I suppose I am correct in assuming (after some googling) that Python doesn't use the installed version of OpenSSL, but uses its own ssl module instead, and has to be rebuilt to upgrade it.

This is on a Raspberry Pi, small non-GUI image based on Raspbian Jessie. I am planning a full rebuild based on a current distribution later when time permits, for now I want to just upgrade the important packages manually.

I cloned the OpenSSL source from git, checked out the 1.1.1-stable branch and built it; just default `configure`, `make`, `make test` and `sudo make install`.

Now I'm trying to rebuild Python to use this version.

I got it to work with Python 3, but it fails in Python 2.
Both are tarballs downloaded today from www.python.org/downloads/source/, built with `./configure` and `make` without any additional options.

Result for 3.7.3: make succeeds, and so does this test

```
$ ./python -c "import ssl; print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)"
OpenSSL 1.1.1d-dev  xx XXX xxxx
```

The old (installed) version of Python reports OpenSSL 1.0.1t for python as well as python3, so the new build is using the new version.

Result for 2.7.16: make only partially succeeds, but ends with

```
Failed to build these modules:
_hashlib           _ssl
```

and the same test goes

```
$ ./python -c "import ssl; print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/src/python/Python-2.7.16/Lib/ssl.py", line 98, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: No module named _ssl
```

Make output when building those modules:

```
building '_ssl' extension
gcc -pthread -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I. -IInclude -I./Include -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/src/python/Python-2.7.16/Include -I/usr/local/src/python/Python-2.7.16 -c /usr/local/src/python/Python-2.7.16/Modules/_ssl.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/usr/local/src/python/Python-2.7.16/Modules/_ssl.o
gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/usr/local/src/python/Python-2.7.16/Modules/_ssl.o -L/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -L/usr/local/lib -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/_ssl.so
*** WARNING: renaming "_ssl" since importing it failed: build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/_ssl.so: undefined symbol: OPENSSL_sk_num
building '_hashlib' extension
gcc -pthread -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I. -IInclude -I./Include -I/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/src/python/Python-2.7.16/Include -I/usr/local/src/python/Python-2.7.16 -c /usr/local/src/python/Python-2.7.16/Modules/_hashopenssl.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/usr/local/src/python/Python-2.7.16/Modules/_hashopenssl.o
gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/usr/local/src/python/Python-2.7.16/Modules/_hashopenssl.o -L/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -L/usr/local/lib -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/_hashlib.so
*** WARNING: renaming "_hashlib" since importing it failed: build/lib.linux-armv7l-2.7/_hashlib.so: undefined symbol: OPENSSL_init_crypto
```

Comment: I still have to verify it, but I think the answer is "yes, it can be built with openssl 1.1.1", and I think I found why it didn't work for me on stack overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42111198/undefined-symbol-openssl-sk-num

Answer (score 1):

As in my comment at the question, the answer is yes.

[Edit: first I thought it was my CFLAGS, but not.]

Finally got it. The build command for the _ssl module contains these switches:
`-L/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf -L/usr/local/lib`

The first of those two locations still contained an OLD (1.0.0) version of libssl.so. The right version was at the second path.

The funny thing is, that seems to have made no difference when building 3.7.3, only for 2.7.16.